# Getting error in Linux printing Security group in azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python, azure-security-center

I have this code and I have written it in windows. and it works fine in windows but when I run it on Linux and I have to run it on Linux as of my project needs and it does not works there and gives me the following error

> AttributeError: 'ServicePrincipalCredentials' object has no attribute
> 'get_token'

```
from azure.mgmt.security import SecurityCenter
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
import Credentials
from pprint import pprint

client = SecurityCenter(Credentials.credential,Credentials.subscription_id,asc_location="")

for score in client.secure_scores.list():
   print(score)
```

Comment: There's lots of results if you google that error, can you share what you've tried so we don't waste yours and our time by suggesting things you've already done? If you haven't yet searched for the error then please do that first.

Comment: I have searched and tried my best That's why I am asking here. why is it working on windows but not on Linux? the Libraries and their versions all are smae

Comment: So you tried running `pip install azure-identity` for instance? Have you ensured that you're running the exact same version of each library, and their dependencies, and the same version of Python, on both systems?

Comment: yes I have double-checked every library version 2 3 times

Comment: I have generated the `req.txt` file from windows and installed it in Linux. also compared every library with versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using latest version of azure-mgmt-security, it works with azure-identity package.

e.g.instead of from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials, you can use from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential.

(I work in MS in the SDK team)